# How to sum values from form text field array using jquery onlick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to jQuery and javascript, I need a help on how to do computation on form text field in an array.  See below sample code;

```
<head lang="en">
  <meta chartaxt="UTF-8">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample salary computation</title>

</head>

<body>

  <form method="POST" name="regis" id="regis">
    <table align="center" border="1" width="200">
      <tr>
        <th>Staff ID</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Total Tax</th>
        <th>Total Net Pay</th>
      </tr>

      <!--Staff 1-->
      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/001">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/001" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="500">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/002">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/002" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="500">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="50">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/003">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/003" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="600">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

I want a jquery script that can sum  total = (salary + tax) for each staff  using onclick button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".salary")) {
      var salary = parseInt($(this).find(".salary").val(), 10)
      var tax = parseInt($(this).find(".tax").val(), 10)
      $(this).find(".total").val(salary + tax)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="regis" id="regis">
  <table align="center" border="1" width="200">
    <tr>
      <th>Staff ID</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Total Tax</th>
      <th>Total Net Pay</th>


    </tr>

    <!--Staff 1-->
    <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/001">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/001" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="500">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/002">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/002" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="500">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="50">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/003">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/003" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hi Harz, I just run the code above, once i click on submit button alert box displays undefined and the total does not show any result

Comment: @NelsonOko-oza Are there any errors in your console? I'm confused because it works fine for me.

Comment: @arz 4 , The result is not showing inside the total text field. I actually wanted the sum of tax and salary to appear inside the total text field

Comment: You mean inside the "Total Net Pay" field or the "Total Tax" field?

Comment: Yes @arz 4, I want the result to appear inside "Total Net Pay" field

Comment: Well I'm still not sure why you aren't seeing the same results I'm seeing when running the code snippet.  Maybe the jsfiddle I added will work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118061/discussion-between-larz-and-nelson-oko-oza).

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector to get or set the val with iQuery. Something like this

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var total = $("input[name=salary]").val()+$("input[name=tax]").val();
    $("input[name=total]").val(tatal);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

http://codepen.io/tryggvigy/pen/BzAqGR

```
var sums = []
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  var salaries = $('.salary')
    .toArray()
    .map(function(salary) { return salary.value })
  var taxes = $('.tax')
    .toArray()
    .map(function(tax) { return tax.value})
  sums = salaries.map(function(salary, i) {
    return parseInt(salary) + parseInt(taxes[i])
  })
  alert(document.sums)
})
```